# localhost refused to connect( i use Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

image.

[get this image on run my code tired cannot solve this problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw6pi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your IIS express, If your IIS Server isn't running try running your project in visual studio and check whether the IIS Server is active.

Right-click the project in Solution Explorer. ...
For Profile, select the New button. ...
For the Launch setting, select IIS from the list.
In the Environment variables section, select the Add button. ...
In the Web Server Settings area, set the App URL to the same value used for the Launch browser endpoint URL

[image]
[image]

Comment: i'm not use iis i run from vs 2021